# Node.js - Prevent user from opening my .js file which contains database details?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

so I am running Node.js with Socket.io
I have a file called service.js, it contains mysql connection details.

So the problem is: I can easily type `www.mysite.com/service.js`

and it just shows plain text, password, login etc for database.
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your non-public files under your static file handler's base directory.